# How to executes a .bat file on local machine from adobe air application?

Tags: apache-flex, air, window, adobe

I m using flex4.6 and i wanted to run a .bat file from ma air application, is there any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

This class might helpful for you my_command.bat  echo "Hello Native Process"

Before run applications (Projectname-app.xml) check supportedProfiles tag

desktop extendedDesktop mobileDevice exendedMobileDevice

to

extendedDesktop

```
package
{

  import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.filesystem.File;

import mx.controls.Alert;

public class PlatformPackaging
{
    private var nativeProcess:NativeProcess;
    private var isErrorOccured:Boolean;

    private var batFile:File;
    private var cmdFile:File;

    private function get isWindows():Boolean
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function PlatformPackaging()
    {
    }

    public function start(targetPlatform:String):void
    {
        if(isWindows)
        {
            batFile = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("publish/my_command.bat");
            cmdFile = new File("c:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
        } 

        proceedToPackaging();
    }


    private function proceedToPackaging():void {

        var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>;

        processArgs.push("/c");
        processArgs.push(batFile.nativePath);

        var workingDirectory:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("publish/");
        var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();

        nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = cmdFile;
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory = workingDirectory;

        nativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
        nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA,onStandardErrorOutputDataHandler);
        nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA,onStandardOutputDataHandler);
        nativeProcess.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
    }

    private function onStandardErrorOutputDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent) : void
    {
        var certResponse:String = nativeProcess.standardError.readUTFBytes(nativeProcess.standardError.bytesAvailable);

        trace(certResponse);
        nativeProcess.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA,onStandardOutputDataHandler);
        nativeProcess.exit();
    }

    Alert.show(certResponse,'Error');
}

protected function onStandardOutputDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var status:String = nativeProcess.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(nativeProcess.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);

    Alert.show(status)
}
 }
}
```

Please let me know any clarification.

Comment: hey raja that above code is shows error in my .as class n that shows :-  The protected attribute can only be used on class property definitions. for last function onStandardOutputDataHandler.

Comment: Oops!.Corrected please put 2 close braces at last

Comment: Also please make sure that you have to create publish dir (which contains our .bat file) inside src folder of your adobe air project.if you follow above class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NativeProcess` class.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html